# Button to View transform segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a custom `UIStoryBoardSegue` in my project and I want to make a transition with it from button. It must be something like this:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class VEShowDialogSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        var _sourceViewController : ContactsViewController = self.sourceViewController as! ContactsViewController
        var _destinationViewController : DialogViewController = self.destinationViewController as! DialogViewController

        var startingPoint = _sourceViewController.dialogButton.center

        _sourceViewController.view.addSubview(_destinationViewController.view)

        var transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05)
        _destinationViewController.view.transform = transform
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05)
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, startingPoint.x, startingPoint.y)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            _destinationViewController.view.transform = transform

            }, completion: {
                (value: Bool) in
                _destinationViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
                _sourceViewController.presentViewController(_destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

        })
    }
}
```

but it's working very poorly. How can I achieve same transition effect?

Also, I must say, that the `sourceViewController` is a `UIViewController`, embedded in Navigation Controller and `destinationViewController` is also a `UIViewController`, embedded in Navigation Controller, but another.

Thanks!